# How does dismissing my familiar from the Find Familiar spell interact with the Flock of Familiars spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, summoning

In the wording of the *[Flock of Familiars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flock-of-familiars)* spell (*Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*, p. 57), we find:

> You temporarily **summon** three familiars – spirits that take animal forms of your choice. Each familiar uses the same rules and options for a familiar conjured by the *find familiar* spell. All the familiars conjured by this spell must be the same type of creature (celestials, fey, or fiends; your choice). If you already have a familiar **conjured** by the *find familiar* spell or similar means, then one fewer familiars are conjured by this spell.

Meanwhile, in the *[Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar)* spell, we're given:

> As an action, you can temporarily **dismiss** your familiar. It disappears into a pocket dimension where it awaits your summons. Alternatively, you can dismiss it forever. As an action while it is temporarily dismissed, you can cause it to reappear in any unoccupied space within 30 feet of you.

Of interest, **conjure** is synonymous to **summon**, which is antonymous to **dismiss**.

If I were to temporarily dismiss my familiar from *Find Familiar* and cast *Flock of Familiars* at level 2, would I expect to summon three new familiars, since the original is no longer conjured? Could my initial familiar then be re-summoned back on top of those already present, making a total of four?

Comment: @Mwr247 how does that  title look?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

Granted, I only know the part of the spell from *Lost Laboratory of Kwalish* that you posted, not owning the book or having read it, but I think it's enough. 
 It specifies that

> If you already have a familiar conjured by the *find familiar* spell or similar means, then one fewer familiars are conjured by this spell.

If you have a regular familiar by the *Find Familiar* spell, it has still been conjured, even if it exists in a pocket dimension. It will remain conjured until it is dispelled or killed.

My proof for this is that the same wording exists in the official *Find Familiar* spell.

> You can't have more than one familiar at a time. If you cast this spell while you already have a familiar, you instead cause it to adopt a new form.

Here we see that you can only have 1 familiar at a time (per this spell) - and even if it has been dismissed into a pocket dimension, casting the spell again would not create a new familiar - only change the form of the one that has been dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

### No

While the wording is slightly ambiguous, I think the design intent is pretty clear:

> If you already have a familiar conjured by the *find familiar* spell or similar means, then one fewer familiars are conjured by this spell.

The design intent of the [Flock of Familiars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/lost-laboratory-of-kwalish) quote above is specifically to prevent what you're attempting to do. If simply dismissing the familiar (a basic function of [Find Familiar](https://thebombzen.com/grimoire/spells/find-familiar)) was all you had to do to get around it, it'd seem pointless to put it in there in the first place.